# Забыл при создании сделать поле с ID AI

Tags: mysql, sql

При создании таблицы забыл сделать поле AI. Как сейчас, не дропая, сделать определённое поле AI?

Comment: ALTER TABLE tablename ADD COLUMN columnname type(length)

Comment: Сначала заполнить, потом объявить AI, установив корректное начальное значение.. AI может быть только на primary key...

Comment: @axmed2004 и что это сделает?

Comment: @Павел Кушнеревич это сделает то что вы спросили

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
CHANGE COLUMN colom colom INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Рекомендую использовать для работы с базами данных HeidiSql вместо того же PhpMyadmin, здесь гораздо лучше все реализовано, понятная документация и интерфейс. Работа с индексами и полями в том числе.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]